# html code to open a file:// link in chrome browser that uses the chrome extension "open in IE" by default

Tags: html, wordpress

Assuming everybody uses chrome browser;

So I am creating a wordpress blog for some friends. We use a shared network, and I want to create a link on that blog that when pressed opens up a folder in internet explorer.

The current html code is

I am using a chrome extension called "open in IE" , but to use it requires a right click then choosing an option within the menu. This process is too long and I want to simplify it.

Is there any html code I can write that make it open that file:// link using the "open in IE" extension by default? The goal is to be able to left click the link in chrome and have a window explorer open with the files in it.

Cheers

Comment: I do not think so, apart from just using IE. Why you would want to use IE is a mystery.

Comment: the goal is to be able to open a windows folder using that link in chrome (and not just a emulation the windows folder within the browser, i need the actual windows folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, targetting a specific browser to open on a clicked link is not possible.

Unless you modified some of their internal registry or used an activex plugin, it is just not a supported feature at this time.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. is there another way to easily implement a link on my blog that would let my network users click it and open up a windows folder on the network within chrome?

Comment: i do not have access to changing reg or activex, it must be done within the html code and perhaps with a simple chrome extension.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I do not currently know of any way to make that possible.

Comment: Well, I did answer the question technically :-) If you feel obliged, feel free to mark as accepted with the green check near the voting arrows.

Comment: Ive hired two software / website technicians to help me with my website, hopefully it will be up in a weeks time :)

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to hard code some javascript.

I believe it is possible to reference installed extensions from your code using chrome.extensions.

Reference here, http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html

Comment: what does 'hardcode javascript' mean? sorry i can script in java but not sure what you mean

Comment: All I meant was, you might be able to use Javascript to do what you want.